# My dog won't relieve herself unless we're asleep

Tags: dogs, training

My dog has separation anxiety and seems to get spooked at everything even if there's no need to be.

I tried feeding her at certain times and she won't eat until she wants to. I wait until a while after she eats to take her out, and right before bed I take her out too.

But she will not go to the bathroom outside if she's on a leash. She used to have a backyard to run in and go whenever, but we don't have that anymore since the move. She never relieves herself even on walks. I don't have time for longer walks.

I crate her and can't leave her unsupervised anywhere in the house because she'll go on the floor. Since she's been supervised she won't go unless we are asleep. We put her in the crate at night so that's where she relieves herself and I know she doesn't like it because if she does go in it she whines like crazy in the morning.

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. Was your dog ever punished for going to the bathroom inside the house? Could you leave her in a locked room (like a bathroom) at night where she could have a seperate place to sleep and go potty? Is there a calm place near your house where you could take her to go potty? Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: I don't know much about housebreaking dogs, but I do know that you need to get them on eating/potty schedule like you've been trying to do.  Feed at regular times like you've been trying, but also take way the food when meal time is over, even if the dog ends up missing a meal here and there.  It'll make the dog hungry, and hopefully it will eat the next meal.  Also, don't give it food or water right before you go to sleep or overnight.